# How can i see the forward function of a model which is set up by loading a .pth file?

Tags: pytorch

I a have a .pth file, and I can simply build a network using `model = torch.load("path to .pth")`
But I don't know how it forwards. Is there any way to check the forward function of the model? Thx.

Comment: You do have the model definition right? else how are you instantiating the model in first place? 
you can check the forward pass in your model definition then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your `.pth` file contains the entire dumped model rather than only the state dicts, which is why you're in this dilemma. But in any case, yes, you can actually check the forward function by using the `inspect` library.

```
import inspect
import torch

unknown_model = torch.load('save_path.pth')
print(inspect.getsource(unknown_model.forward))
```